# Ruby on Rails - Has_many through - limit and order by join table attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models:

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :trainings, through: :events
end
```

Event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
end
```

Training

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :user, through: :events
end
```

In my Event table there is user_id and training_id but also a date. This date represents the date that the user undertook a particular training.

For each user I would like to select the most recent event corresponding to different training. For instance a particular user might have had training on basic life support, for example, in 2015 and 2016 but i only want to select the 2016 one. I've tried using scopes but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgres

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the variable `user`

To find his most recent event:

```
user.events.order(:date).first
```

To find his most recent event of a specific training:

```
user.trainings.find_by(subject: "life_support").events.order(:date).first
```

The rails team also has a fantastic guide on this subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Problem is that on my view it ends up displaying all the users trainings rather than the specific user in question: `code` <% @user.trainings.each do |training| %> <%= training.events.order(:date).last.date %>

Comment: I had to do this to get it to work `code` <% @user.trainings.each do |training| %><%= training.events.where(user_id: @user.id).order(:date).last.date %> <% training.events.where(user_id: @user.id).order(:date).reverse_order.each do |event| %>

Comment: Also had to use this in the model `code` has_many :trainings, -> { distinct }, through: :events